# angular textarea update rows number

Tags: angular, textarea

Im updating textarea rows attribute using angular 4 as a reaction of keyup event.
Here is component code

```
export class AutoResizedTextareaComponent {
  rows : number = 1;

  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

  onKey(event: Event) { 
    while(event.srcElement.clientHeight < event.srcElement.scrollHeight) {
    this.rows++;
    }
  }
}
```

and here is template `<textarea [(rows)]="rows" (keyup)="onKey($event)"></textarea>`

Changing rows should change clientHeight, it was working when I used if instead of while, but while is blocking ui, clientHeight stay the same so I have endless loop here. I tried to use NgZone but it didn't solved this problem.

Comment: `clientHeight` won't be updated until the browser redraws everything so what you've got is an infinite loop

Comment: can you use an if statement instead of while? https://plnkr.co/edit/hiowRK6fVOcGHZuGtOEw?p=preview

Comment: My purpose is to have textbox which is changing it's height depending on it's content. If statement is not good enough, if user paste a lot of text into a textbox if will increase rows only by one, so I need while loop here.